# How can I customize json output from spring rest controller

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a POJO class patient with the below properties:

```
public class Patient implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
    private String username;
    private String password;

....
```

Now from my rest controller I need to send only name, phoneNo, email and address of patient in the json.
I expect the json output as

```
{
   "check":"Success",
   "details":{
      "name":"Test User",
      "phoneNo":"9876544321",
      "email":"test@gmail.com",
      "address":"Address"
   }
}
```

Here check Success/Failure is just added as a flag only.

Comment: If at all possible, avoid doing this; it's obnoxious. Success/failure is literally the whole point of HTTP status codes.

Comment: If what you want to do is to transform the response format according to different requests, you can try **jolt** - a json to json transformer. It can transform the output json content or format with customized configuration for each request.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create another object and use it as the response of your restful controller;

```
public class PatientResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private Check check;
    private Detail details;

    // getter, setter, etc

    public static class Detail {

        private String name;
        private String phoneNo;
        private String email;
        private String address;

        // getters, setters, etc
    }

    public enum Check {
        Success, Failure
    }
}
```

& in controller

```
@RestController
public class PatientController {

    @GetMapping(...)
    public PatientResponse get(...) {
        Patient patient = ... // get patient somehow
        return mapPatientToResponse(patient);  // map Patient to PatientResponse here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. can we resolve this using json mapper/filter. There are multiple endpoints that will show different properties of patient class.I have informed just one.

Comment: @devD you'd have to create individual response objects for all those different endpoint requirements, that is how RESTful works, you can check GraphQL if you are interested in mapping from the client side.

Comment: Your answer is simple and it has worked fine.Thank you. Actually I wanted to apply json filter inside controller.

Comment: @devD I'd recommend against using same object and filtering it with such methods for multiple endpoints, if any requirements change, you'd have a bigger trouble with such a coupled design, better to have individual entity per specific set of requirements that are for each individual endpoint. You can utilize some clever mapping tools to speed up the implementation since biggest cost is those boring mapper methods...

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot uses Jackson for JSON serialization and deserialization, try using @JSonIgnore (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore).

Answer (score 0):

### For your request

PatientDTO.java

```java
public class PatientDTO {
    private Check check;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id", "dob", "username", "password"})
    private Object details;

    /* Getter & Setter */

    public enum Check {
        SUCCESS("Success"),
        FAILURE("Failure");

        private String name;

        Check(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @JsonValue
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller demo:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/patient")
    public PatientDTO getPatient() {
        PatientDTO patientDTO = new PatientDTO();
        patientDTO.setCheck(PatientDTO.Check.SUCCESS);
        patientDTO.setDetails(new Patient());
        return patientDTO;
    }
}
```

### A Better way

use http status

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Patient {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    /* Getter & Setter */
}
```

Controller demo:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("patient")
    // or @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Patient> patient() {
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setId(123);
        patient.setName("123");
        patient.setEmail("demo@demo.com");
        patient.setPassword(null); // set to null to ignore password
        return ResponseEntity.ok(patient);
    }
}
```